# Is it possible to test 'Image Upload' function on my React Native app without database/server?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, file-upload, mobile-development

I'm a beginner in mobile app development and I'm writing an app using React Native to practice. I want to add the **'Upload Image'** box on one of my pages but I don't know how to test it.

[I want to try something like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuE8y.png)

ChatGPT gives lots of suggestions and I think there is some good ones, but I want to get some answers from real developers.

Also this is my first question here :)

Comment: What do you want to test? It's possible to create a click dummy or "upload" it to the local device.

Comment: What does 'create a click dummy' means?

Comment: What does upload without db and server mean? Where do you want to upload it?

Comment: I actually don't want to upload it anywhere yet, I want the code work. While still coding my page I want to be able to use my Android phone and test if the Upload Image function is working (select picture from gallery, take a picture). I don't know if it makes sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use React Native Image Picker.

First install the package:

```
yarn add react-native-image-picker
```

Then you'll need to link some dependencies in your android and ios project files. Run this command in your project directory.

```
react-native link react-native-image-picker
```

Edit your android manifest to add permissions. This way the device will ask the user for permission to use the functionality you're looking for.

`Project → android → app → src → debug → AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

That all should get you to a point where you can use the package. From here, you may want to look at [the documenation](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker) for your specific situation. For reference, here's an example of the package being used. If you'd like, you can paste this code into your app.js and it should do what you're asking:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  Button,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  customButtons: [{ name: 'fb', title: 'Choose Photo from Facebook' }],
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filepath: {
        data: '',
        uri: ''
      },
      fileData: '',
      fileUri: ''
    }
  }

  chooseImage = () => {
    let options = {
      title: 'Select Image',
      customButtons: [
        { name: 'customOptionKey', title: 'Choose Photo from Custom Option' },
      ],
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        alert(response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };

        // You can also display the image using data:
        // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
        // alert(JSON.stringify(response));s
        console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
          filePath: response,
          fileData: response.data,
          fileUri: response.uri
        });
      }
    });
  }

  launchCamera = () => {
    let options = {
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        alert(response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
          filePath: response,
          fileData: response.data,
          fileUri: response.uri
        });
      }
    });

  }

  launchImageLibrary = () => {
    let options = {
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        alert(response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
        this.setState({
          filePath: response,
          fileData: response.data,
          fileUri: response.uri
        });
      }
    });

  }

  renderFileData() {
    if (this.state.fileData) {
      return <Image source={{ uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.state.fileData }}
        style={styles.images}
      />
    } else {
      return <Image source={require('./assets/dummy.png')}
        style={styles.images}
      />
    }
  }

  renderFileUri() {
    if (this.state.fileUri) {
      return <Image
        source={{ uri: this.state.fileUri }}
        style={styles.images}
      />
    } else {
      return <Image
        source={require('./assets/galeryImages.jpg')}
        style={styles.images}
      />
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <Text style={{textAlign:'center',fontSize:20,paddingBottom:10}} >Pick Images from Camera & Gallery</Text>
            <View style={styles.ImageSections}>
              <View>
                {this.renderFileData()}
                <Text  style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Base 64 String</Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                {this.renderFileUri()}
                <Text style={{textAlign:'center'}}>File Uri</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.btnParentSection}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.chooseImage} style={styles.btnSection}  >
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Choose File</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.launchCamera} style={styles.btnSection}  >
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Directly Launch Camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.launchImageLibrary} style={styles.btnSection}  >
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Directly Launch Image Library</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },

  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height - 20,
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width
  },
  ImageSections: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  images: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 3
  },
  btnParentSection: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop:10
  },
  btnSection: {
    width: 225,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#DCDCDC',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginBottom:10
  },
  btnText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'gray',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight:'bold'
  }
});
```

Here's the tutorial I'm referencing:

https://medium.com/enappd/how-to-pick-images-from-camera-gallery-in-react-native-app-faf58f26ee37

Comment: Oh no I actually want to be able to test if my function is working. Even if I'm not uploading any picture to the database I want to see the options Take a Picture/Select from Gallery on my screen when I click the button. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Edited my response. I think I found what you're looking for :)

Comment: @jabaa Thank you for the heads up. I added details to the answer. Am I allowed to leave the link to the tutorial up, considering it's a reference used in the answer?

Comment: @NazYasar Does this answer work for you? If so, I'd love if you'd accept the answer. If not, I'm happy to help further :)